# How to add column with different values while CREATING MATERIALIZED VIEW?

Tags: postgresql, select, materialized-views

I am creating a materialized view from several different tables, but I am missing the class value because it's not in the origin tables. How can I add a column and set the value while creating the materialized view? I'd like to get ONE new column called class and fill it for every SELECT with it's name to be able to filter the MV later. I know you can add the column straight to the origin table but since the table always gets dropped and filled back up again from a different person, I'd like to do it directly in the MV.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW vt_views.poi
TABLESPACE pg_default
AS
SELECT tim_bergname.name,
       tim_bergname.info1 AS hoehe,
       NULL AS art,
       NULL AS name_alternative,
       tim_bergname.info2 AS region,
       NULL AS text_hoehe,
       NULL AS name_lang,
       tim_bergname.geoloc,
       tim_bergname.symbolnummer
FROM tim_bergname

UNION ALL

SELECT tim_haus_huette.name,
       NULL,
       tim_haus_huette.info1 AS art,
       NULL,
       tim_haus_huette.info2 AS region,
       NULL,
       NULL,
       tim_haus_huette.geoloc,
       tim_haus_huette.symbolnummer
FROM tim_haus_huette

UNION ALL

... severall other SELECTS

UNION ALL

SELECT tim_wohnmobilstellplatz.name,
       NULL,
       NULL,
       NULL,
       NULL,
       NULL,
       NULL,
       tim_wohnmobilstellplatz.geoloc,
       tim_wohnmobilstellplatz.symbolnummer
FROM tim_wohnmobilstellplatz
WITH DATA;
```

And the index:

```
CREATE INDEX poi_geoloc_idx
    ON vt_views.poi USING gist (geoloc)
TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "class value"?

Comment: After the MV is created you can't tell which object is from which origin table. The column should be named "klasse" and has the name from each SELECT Table inside like "tim_wohnmobilstellplatz" so I can order and filter where they are coming from.

Comment: So you want the tablename listed in the column `class`?

Comment: yes that would be perfect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do that:

Use the `tableoid` system column:

```
SELECT tableoid::regclass::text as class,
       tim_bergname.name,
       tim_bergname.info1 AS hoehe,
       NULL AS art,
       NULL AS name_alternative,
       tim_bergname.info2 AS region,
       NULL AS text_hoehe,
       NULL AS name_lang,
       tim_bergname.geoloc,
       tim_bergname.symbolnummer
FROM tim_bergname
```

Or simply add a constant value:

```
SELECT 'tim_bergname' as class,
       tim_bergname.name,
       tim_bergname.info1 AS hoehe,
       NULL AS art,
       NULL AS name_alternative,
       tim_bergname.info2 AS region,
       NULL AS text_hoehe,
       NULL AS name_lang,
       tim_bergname.geoloc,
       tim_bergname.symbolnummer
FROM tim_bergname
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much